# UIPickerView - one component as image, the other as text

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am trying to create a two component UIPickerView, the left side of which holds the values of playing cards (two, three, Jack, etc.) and the right side of which holds images of the four suits. Here is the relevant code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
      return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
      if (component == 0)
            return [self.values count];
      return [self.column1 count];
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
         titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
        forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
      if (component == 0)
            return [self.values objectAtIndex:row];
      else 
            return nil;
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
      if(component == 1){
          NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column1"];
          NSArray *array = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
          return [array objectAtIndex:row];
      }
      else
           return nil;
}
```

As you can probably see, I have attempted to create a separate picker delegate method for the left component and the right component. However, this is not giving me the intended results. The code seems to only run the viewForRow method, ignoring the other. Thus, I end up with the right component filled with images and the left component empty. Does anybody know of a different way to populate both components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably as soon, as you implement `viewForRow:`, it wins over `titleForRow:`.

Just return an `UILabel` with the needed text. After all `titleForRow:` doesn't do anything else. It's just a more convinient way, if you ONLY need labels.

Comment: Also your code seems a little bit weird. In the `viewForRow:` method you could just use `[self.column1 objectAtIndex: row]` directly instead of the three lines you have at the moment.